# Как в телефонном номере при помощи регулярного выражения удалить первую цифру

Tags: html

Как в телефонном номере при помощи регулярного выражения удалить первую цифру

Comment: А почему бы не проверять первую цифру? Если она равна 7 или +, то вырезаем

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('+79001002030'.replace(/(\+?)\d(\d+)/, '$1$2'));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Есть ещё какие то варианты? Программа копирует полностью номер с 7, мне надо чтобы она вставляла в программу без первой 7

Comment: Как в программе Bas вырезать в телефонном номере первую цифру 7? Чтобы при копировании с сайта, в программу Bas вставлялся номер без первой цифры 7. Спасибо за ответы